# How to see a list of Custom Object created date?

Tags: custom-object

I can I see a list/report of custom objects with Created Date listed as a column ?

Is this something I can do in Workbench...?

Comment: Hmm, wait, the answer I links is about `CreatedBy`, the query is just about the same for what you're after. Just do `SELECT CreatedDate, DeveloperName FROM CustomObject`.

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian. I really appreciate the reference !